# Is 「<number>回後」 equivalent to 「第<number>回」?

Tags: translation, nuances

For example, I'm trying to make sense of the following phrase:

> 二回後システム

When **literally** translated to English, becomes:

> Twice After System

I have also encountered a similar phrase:

> システム第2回

Can both phrases mean "System Version 2"? If no, what makes them different?

Comment: Can you give the complete sentences they appeared in?  Or some other context to make sense of them?

Comment: @snailplane They're not in any sentences. They only appear once under the column "applications" and that's about it. Sorry. :(

Comment: What is the document about? What other similar words are there? What's in the other columnts? The more context you provide, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that neither 二回後システム nor システム第2回 makes any sense in my native ears even though I could feel you tried hard.

To use as much as possible from one of those two, one could take the latter and alter it to 「システム[第二版]{だいにばん}」, but the more natural way of saying "System Version 2" nowadays would be 「システム・バージョン[2]{ツー}」.

Comment: Can it be possible that 二回後 is a proper name? As in Nikaigo? 

[I think I should have asked for the meaning of 二回後システム, but since it's another question on its own and this answer satisfies the question, I will mark this as accepted.]